# HTML saved in json with doctrine - read in twig dump

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, twig

I got json saved in database:

```
{"payments_methods":{"name":"PayPal","status":"1","prowizja":"20","opis":"<p><img alt=\"\" height=\"93\" src=\"\/uploads\/images\/\/PayPal.svg.png\" width=\"350\" \/><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>P\u0142atno\u015b\u0107 po przez system PayPal. Uzupe\u0142nij dane i kliknij zap\u0142a\u0107.<\/p>\r\n","kraj":["1"],"save":"","_token":"ZwhJdI7CEa1itN1ad4lJayiliy35eAMOShnCJvqipbw"}}
```

Output in twig if i dump this array is:

```
Payments {#1757 ▼
  -id: 27
  -json: array:1 [▼
    "payments" => array:4 [▼
      "status" => 1
      "method" => array:7 [▼
        "name" => "PayPal"
        "status" => "1"
        "prowizja" => "20"
        "opis" => ""
        "kraj" => array:1 [▶]
        "save" => ""
        "_token" => "EQohfJGK5v4DpFgzQhfeqV3DRtVetbCK6xB7Gq_wKec"
      ]
      "client" => array:21 [▶]
      "total" => "395.20"
    ]
  ]
  -invoice: null
  -orders: Orders {#1762 ▶}**
```

and problem is that in payments.json.payments.opis value is empty, in database is that what i pasted before. Why symfony not read it correct ?

In database this field is:

```
"opis":"<p><img alt=\"\" height=\"93\" src=\"\/uploads\/images\/\/PayPal.svg.png\" width=\"350\" \/><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>P\u0142atno\u015b\u0107 po przez system PayPal. Uzupe\u0142nij dane i kliknij zap\u0142a\u0107.<\/p>\r\n"
```

---

Just cleared the cache :p

Comment: Maybe the Vardumper blocks the HTML, is data here if you only print content of `opis` ?

Comment: Curious - have you tried using `<br>` instead of `\r\n` in your code? There might be an issue with not escaping that.

Comment: I forgot to say that content come from ckeditor bundle in symfony 4.1

Comment: Hi! The problem was, that cache catching it. Very strange... but its all ok. Thank you for your time.